# Problem with \begin{document} and alignment?

Tags: align

I'm a noob in Latex. After watching some videos on Utube I tried to type up some maths on Latex. Btw I'm using the latest version on my Mac.
The default preambles are already there so I started with the \begin{document} and \end{document} as suggested by the video tutorials. A list of error messages came up.

[image: Error messages from \begin{document} and \end{document}]

However if I remove them, the text does turn up, but aligned to the right automatically.
[image: text aligned to the right]
I tried adding \begin{flushleft}  and  \end{flush left} and I got a list of error messages again.

Another problem is that the text seems to get cut off when it's too long. Do I need to create line breaks automatically?
[image: text got cut off]

Thx in advance!:)

Comment: According to their website `LaTeXiT` is sort of an equation editor. This means the default preamble has already added the some of the packages and macros you need and repeating them is causing the problem. Try to copy your complete code (with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`and etc) in `TeXShop` that is included in MaCTeX and see what happens.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, as I hadn't realized how LaTeXit works, sorry about that.

Comment: `\text` is defined (in `amsmath`) to be used in math.  although i haven't checked, i suspect it won't behave properly *outside of* math.  this suspicion is reinforced by the message that a `$` (the math toggle) has been inserted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Outside math `\text` expands to `\mbox` without the possibility for line breaks.

Comment: tbanks, @HeikoOberdiek.  then, put simply, there's no good reason to use `\text` outside math.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the full picture, at the bottom there are four modes of compilation in LaTeXiT: inline, display, align and text. So we don't know in which one you are (probably “Align”). So

- You don't need `\begin{document}` or `\end{document}`
- `\text` is only for math mode (since you are in “Align”, it's acceptable, but you could remove `\text` and use “Text mode”)
- Since you are in align, and you are not using `&` (alignment characters), it aligns the lines at the end, as always.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but, if you want text… why don't you compile with a usual editor? LaTeXiT is thought (IMO) just to create small images or .pdfs with equations or things that you *need* in LaTeX, and you can't use them in your workflow (for instance, if you use Word).